# macbook pro 15 inch retina, keyboard shortcut for desktop display

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, desktop

I have the latest MacBook Pro 15 inch with Retina display, **OS 10.8.4**. Not wanting to use the standard <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys but use them as Apple has assigned them.

**Is there a keyboard shortcut to display the desktop?** I find the finger drag on the trackpad literally a drag!

Thanks, Carin

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd> works for me.  If you have *Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys* turned on in System Preferences > Keyboard, then it would have to be <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to System Preferences -> Mission Control
2. Assign your own keyboard shortcut to Show Desktop.

Answer (score -1):

Just press command + F3
And repeat the same command to bring the windows back.

Comment: This adds nothing that wasn't already said in the first answer from 5 years ago.